# How to mark specific resources as exception in AWS config

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

We have started using AWS config for compliance reasons, but some resources are exceptions and we would like AWS config to ignore those specific resources as they are managed by a third-party CI/CD pipeline. For example, if we have 10 EC2 instances, can we add an exception in AWS config to skip checking some EC2 instances out of 10? I could not find any way at this point. Is there any workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: Create custom rules that will skip resources which you want to skip.